# Как не парсить определенный div блок

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

вот у меня есть парсер который работает как надо, но есть один изъян, при парсинге так же захватывается ненужный мне блок который находится на каждой странице, в котором мусорные товары которые мне нужно очистить:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я мог бы это сделать?

Вот код, который делает запрос на получение данных:

```
            for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".product .tabloid"):
                name = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.name', 'Null')
                price = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.price', '-')
                nal = get_text_by_css(item_el, '', '-')

                row = name, price, nal
                print(row)

                items.append(row)
```

Вот ссылка на страницу:

https://notebooker.ua/search/?q=Gazer&send=Y&r=Y

Результат выполнение программы:

```
('Електропривод багажника GAZER TG-7P5', '25 999 грн.', '-')
('Електропривод багажника GAZER TG-5N2', '25 999 грн.', '-')
('Електропривод багажника GAZER TG-A50', '25 999 грн.', '-')
('Електропривод багажника GAZER TG-A40', '25 999 грн.', '-')
('Відеокамера GAZER CF730-IN', '1 499 грн.', '-')
('Система кругового огляду GAZER CKR4400', '11 599 грн.', '-')
('Монітор 23.6 Iiyama X2474HS-B2', '4 835 грн.\n5 619 грн.', '-') # С этой строки начинает парсить мусор
('Монітор 23.6 Iiyama XB2481HS-B1/XB2481HS-B1 C', '5 420 грн.\n6 299 грн.', '-')
('Монітор LENOVO S28u-10 (61E6GAT2UA)', '8 105 грн.\n8 829 грн.', '-')
('Esperanza KETTLE EKK018 WHITE-GREY (EKK018E)', '215 грн.\n269 грн.', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
('', '', '-')
Load: https://notebooker.ua/search/?q=Gazer&send=Y&r=Y&PAGEN_1=2
```

Если понадобится, вот полный код программы: https://dpaste.org/yynJ

Comment: Нужно найти такой родительский элемент, в котором находятся товары до пагинации. Попробовал посмотреть такой на сайте, а он `This site is temporarily unavailable.` :)

Comment: Действительно, оказалось если включить голову то можно такой найти)
Этим элементом оказался селектор `#catalogColumn .product`

Comment: Молодец, что разобрались :) Оформите сами ответ :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для того что бы решить данный вопрос потребовалось определить родительный селектор для позиций находящихся вне того блока который нам не нужен и заменить селектор в коде.

Вот что будет если искать селектор просто наведя мышку на карточку товара
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но если внимательно посмотреть, то над карточкой товара есть еще один `div`, который выдает уже другой селектор, который не захватывает карточки ненужных нам товаров

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Забираем второй селектор и вставляем его в наш код:

```
 for item_el in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#catalogColumn .product"):
                name = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.name', 'Null').strip('Електропривод багажника').strip('Автомобільна мультимедійна система')
                price = get_text_by_css(item_el, '.price', '-')
                nal = get_text_by_css(item_el, '', 'Есть в наличии')

                row = f'{DT.datetime.now():%d-%m-%Y}',name, price, nal
                print(row)

                items.append(row)
```

В итоге вот результат выполнения программы:

```
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-RM4', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-GH', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-TLN', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-DM', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-TL', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-AD1', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-7P5', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-5N2', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-A50', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER TG-A40', '25 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'Відеокамера GAZER CF730-IN', '1 499 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'Система кругового огляду GAZER CKR4400', '11 599 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
Load: https://notebooker.ua/search/?q=Gazer&send=Y&r=Y&PAGEN_1=2
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER ММ-система CM5507-QV (CM5507-QV)', '7 409 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'Відеореєстратор GAZER F125', '2 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'Відеореєстратор GAZER F155', '5 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
('29-10-2021', 'GAZER MUW5000', '5 999 грн.', 'Есть в наличии')
```